# Rufus Windows-To-Go Failure

Tags: windows, windows-10, device, disk, drive

I was trying to use Rufus to make a Windows-To-Go drive and I woke up to it "being used by another software" or something along the lines of that. I could see all the windows files originally but when I unplugged it and plugged it back in, it never showed up. It says "unknown" and "Not initialized" in disk manager but "This device is not ready" when I go to initialize. I used some third party software to try that as well but that didn't work. If anyone can help me, thank you in advance.

Unplugged and plugged in - Doesn't show up
Disk manager - "unknown" and "not initialized" "this device is not ready"
Third party software - shows up "read only", nothing fixes